# XPCOM using Web Workers from a Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, web-worker, xpcom

My Firefox extension is parsing big chunks of data. I would usually use WebWorkers to do this, however in XPCOM I seems that this is not an option. The ChromeWorker, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChromeWorker, seems to be obsolete and "discouraged in new projects".

Are there any options to use workers in a Firefox extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: no, you cannot access XPCOM from a different thread. But that doesn't mean that you cannot use chrome workers.

Long version: Firefox used to allow accessing XPCOM from other threads, e.g. via `ChromeWorker`. This led to all kinds of issues like weird crashes or just plain inconsistent behavior. In the end Mozilla decided that supporting multithreaded XPCOM access was too complicated and error-prone, as was documenting its limitations and stopping people from shooting themselves in the feet.

With current Firefox versions, accessing XPCOM from `ChromeWorker` is no longer possible. `ChromeWorker` itself however isn't deprecated however even though the MDN comment can be easily misread as a general deprecation statement. The idea is that you would use `ChromeWorker` in combination with [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) which will allow you to use native libraries (the ones provided by the operating system, libraries included in Firefox like NSS and libraries distributed with your extension) on a different thread.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, this might work for you. E.g., if you need XPCOM for file access then you don't even need to use js-ctypes directly - [OS.File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File) will do that for you. However, XPCOM access is limited to the main thread.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The app takes css files and parse them by getting trough each character using string.charCodeAt(). This can be expensive. Wanted to get that out of the main thread, not sure if OS.file can help in this case. Thanks.

Comment: @Mircea: If the CSS file is on disk - yes, sure. If the CSS file is somewhere on the web then you will still have to fetch it on the main thread (e.g. via async XMLHttpRequest) and pass the data to the worker then.

Comment: Assuming that I already have the CSS content in a Javascript object/string, can I use OS.File to pass its contents and parse it with my js parser off main thread? Sorry, I am somewhat puzzled by this.

Comment: No, `OS.File` is used to read/write files. In order to communicate between main thread and worker you use messages...